# Prevent vue render newline between elements

Tags: vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span>foo</span> <!-- unwanted space here -->
    <span>bar</span>
    <span>foo</span>
  </div>
</template>

// But I don't want to do this
<template>
  <div>
    <span>
      foo
    </span><span> <!-- bad coding style -->
      bar
    </span><span>
      baz
    </span>
   </div>
</template>
```

In html, newlines between elements are rendered as spaces, and Vue followed that behavior. If I want no spaces between the elements, the obvious way is to put no space there, as shown in the code sample. But it is ugly, I don't want that. How can I do otherwise such that there is no space between the elements?

Comment: Are you referring to HTML formatting (e.g., in an IDE)? Or the code rendered in the build output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the [compiler options](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html).

> compilerOptions
>   type: Object
>
> default: {}
>
> Options for the template compiler. When using the default vue-template-compiler, you can use this option to add custom compiler directives, modules, or discard whitespaces between template tags with { **preserveWhitespace**: false }.

However the documentation states this only applies to single file components and template tags. I don't think there is currently any option for native tags and related [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7701) has been closed. But maybe it gives you the desired result.